# How to prevent chapter titles from appearing in the header on the first page of each chapter in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

To place the chapter title in the header of my document, I used:

```
 \setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[chapter]}][][][{\getmarking[chapter]}]
```

My document is not double-sided. Whenever the chapter title appears on the first page of the chapter, it produces the odd result of seeing the chapter title in the header directly above the actual chapter title, e.g.:

```
 _______________
| Chapter 1     |
|               |
| CHAPTER 1     |
|    Once upon  |
| a time, ...   |
|_______________|
```

How can I place a chapter title in the header, but prevent it from appearing on the first page of each chapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `header` key to control the header of a chapter page,
`empty` suppresses the header on a chapter page.

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [header=empty]
```

More information on the [Wiki - setuphead](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead).

Side note: You don't need to write `\getmarking[chapter]` simply
`chapter` will do just fine.

```
\setupheadertexts
  [chapter][]
  [][chapter]
```