# How to place chapter titles in the header only on the first page of each chapter in ConTeXt?

Tags: header-footer, context, context-mkiv

How can I place the chapter titles in the header, but only on the first page of that chapter? This is the opposite of the question, [How to prevent chapter titles from appearing in the header on the first page of each chapter in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79641/how-to-prevent-chapter-titles-from-appearing-in-the-header-on-the-first-page-of), in other words, the header only displays the title on the first page, not on the other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like your problem, the solution is the inverse of the post you
linked to:
define a header text and apply it to the structural (*chapter*), but
leave the header empty for the rest.

Example:

```
\definetext [chapter:header:text] [header]
  [{\namedstructurevariable{chapter}{title}
    \hfill
    (this goes on the first page exclusively)}]

\setuphead [chapter] [header=chapter:header:text]

\setuppagenumbering [location=footer]

\starttext
  \startchapter[title=foo]
    \dorecurse{3}{\input knuth\page}
  \stopchapter
  \startchapter[title=bar]
    \dorecurse{3}{\input knuth\page}
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Comment: It may be better to use `\getmarking[chapter]` instead of chapter title. That way a use can change the chapter markibg if needed.

Comment: @Aditya have you tested that? I got an error with ``\getmarking``.

Comment: I did not test it. But if you get an error, then that is a bug.